# What is javascript bookmarklet to reset page to initial state after executing previous bookmarklet change?

Tags: javascript, state, reset, bookmarklet

How to reset a page with js bookmarklet as it was after I applied some other bookmarklets without reloading it?
Suppose I run:
`javascript:x1` which changed this page somehow, like adding alts before images or replacing links, etc. 
Is there any `javascipt:reset-state()` to reset page as it was before I used any js on page?

Comment: I suppose you can run `javascript:location.reload()`, but that bookmarklet really just duplicates your browser's own refresh button.

Comment: There's no such thing. Either your bookmarklets are explicitly designed such that you can programmatically reverse each of the effects, or you reload the page.

Comment: You cannot do it with a stardard way. But there might be some instruents for that. E.g. you can use greasemonkey / tampermonkey to store initial `document.body.outerHTML`